# When setting up the Drupal 7 database (mySql/mariadb) what database user accounts should be created?

Tags: database

When installing the database (mariadb) for use with Drupal 7 on Centos 7, what database admin and user accounts should be created and with what permissions?

Do specific directory permissions or file ownerships need to be provisioned for these database user accounts?  -Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one user allowed to create, drop tables, and mysql basic operations (INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELTE, ALTER, INDEX...). In [drupal installation tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/install/step-2-create-the-database) you have more info.